# Can I wire a 3-4-3 way switch circuit with power to switch and lights at the beginning and end of the run?

Tags: wiring, lighting

I made the mistake of not wiring all 3 lights together, only two above the stairwell going to the basement and then a separate light in the basement.  I'm hoping there is an easy wiring path to allow me to add the basement light at the end of run.

Comment: Can you provide a drawing of what you want to do and what you've got?

Comment: Can you run a 14/2 from the stairwell light to the light in the basement?

Comment: NOT enough information to provide an answer.

Comment: I have not done that if from the same panel / breaker , maybe could you provide your proposed schematic so we understand.

Comment: What wiring method are you using? Are you in a position where ripping out your existing work and replacing it is no longer an option?  Also, which switch are you trying to power this from?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want to have 3 switches control several lights which land separately at the start and end of the switch run.

You can do that by using a 14/4 (if on 15A breaker, 12/4 if on 20A) to carry the neutral, travelers forward and switched live back.

That way you have a switched live at every location.

The other option is to split the light cluster and control them separately, but I'd need more detail to suggest a plan to do so.